# Skrollr Style Sheets not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Although it mentions that Skrollr Stylesheets are compatible with IE 8+ I can't seem to get the working on my site. http://group.com/good-to-go-training. Works great in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

For reference: https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr-stylesheets

Comment: This sounds like a bug and there's a better place than StackOverflow: https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr-stylesheets/issues

skrollr-stylesheets is very new and should be used with caution. Please run the unit tests in IE 8 https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37892603/skrollr-stylesheets/test/index.html

Comment: Looking at your source code, I found this `data-no-skrollr { ;}` inside a the stylesheet. And inside some `link` tags, where it should just be `data-no-skrollr`

Answer (score 0):

The tests are now passing it IE 8. Please grab the latest version and make sure to read the changelog! https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr-stylesheets#002